# Importing a font with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, fonts, font-family

I'm trying to get a Google font on my website. It works if I put this code in each HTML file.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I want to be efficient and only access the font in my main CSS file, but I don't understand why the font doesn't display without the HTML part.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Cinzel Decorative";
    src: url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:700") }
html, body {
    background-color: #C00;
    color: #600;
    font-family: "Cinzel Decorative", serif;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    text-align: center }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work that way because the `src` property in a `@font-face` rule must refer to a *font file*, not to a CSS file.

If you really want to use `@font-face` in your own code, you need to download the font, create different formats from it using e.g. [FontSquirrel webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), which also produces a sample file containing the code needed, and upload the relevant files onto your server.

If you just want to do things in CSS instead of using the `link` element, use an `@import` rule at the start of your style sheet. It does not imply any efficiency improvement, though. Example:

```html
<style>
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:700");
html, body {
    background-color: #C00;
    color: #600;
    font-family: "Cinzel Decorative", serif;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700; /* should be used since you refer to 700 weight typeface */
}
</style>
Hello world
```